# Count rows from 1 table that have more than x rows in another table

Tags: dax

I have 3 tables - Folders, Documents & Versions

| FolderID | Folder Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Folder 1 |
| 2 | Folder 2 |
| 3 | Folder 3 |

Documents looks like this:

| DocID | Doc Name | FolderID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Doc 1 | 1 |
| 1001 | Doc 2 | 1 |
| 1002 | Doc 3 | 2 |
| 1003 | Doc 4 | 2 |
| 1004 | Doc 5 | 3 |

Versions looks like this:

| VersionID | DocID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1001 |
| 3 | 1001 |
| 4 | 1002 |
| 5 | 1003 |
| 6 | 1003 |
| 7 | 1004 |

So Doc 1, 3 & 5 have 1 version each, and Doc 2 & 4 have 2 versions.

I would like to count the documents that have more than 1 version.  In this example Folder 1 & 2 both have 1 document with more than 1 version, and Folder 3 has none.

I'd like some DAX that will accomplish that.  I'm managing to confuse myself because the filter is based on a count of a related table.

This is what I came up with, but I know I'm off

```
Count Docs =
VAR VersionsMin = 2
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( 'Documents'[DocID] ),
        FILTER ( 'Versions', COUNT ( 'Versions'[VersionID] ) >= VersionsMin )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

1. In the first step add a new **column** to your *Documents* table

```
Version Count = 
COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE(Versions))
```

2. In the second step you can use this column for filtering

```
Docs with multiple versions = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(Documents[DocID]),
    Documents[Version Count] > 1
)
```

3. This allows you to create the following table visual:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter, that's worked perfectly.  The key thing there was how to count the related rows in the Version table.  Everything was smooth from there.